# create a sql procedure

Tags: sql-server, odbc

im trying to create a procedure query with ms-sql for my game but Im kinda stucked..

Lets say,
I have a database with username and password rows.
I use the procedure query to select the username and password.
If everything is right, then the procedure will output the "result-code"

How I call the procedure query

```
BEGIN_DECLARE_SQLUNIT( SP_AccountSelect, "{ call AccountAuth(?,?) }" )
    BEGIN_VARIABLE()
        char    m_szUserID[MAX_SIZE_USER_ID + 1];
        char    m_szUserPW[MAX_SIZE_USER_ID + 1];
        int     m_nResultCode;
    END_VARIABLE()
    BEGIN_PARAM(3)
        PARAM_ENTRY_STR(SQL_PARAM_INPUT, m_szUserID)
        PARAM_ENTRY_STR(SQL_PARAM_INPUT, m_szUserPW)
        PARAM_ENTRY(SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, m_nResultCode)    
    END_PARAM()
END_DECLARE_SQLUNIT()
```

procedure I have till now:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AccountAuth] /* Procedure Name. */
    @m_szUserID varchar(20),
        @m_szUserPW varchar(50)
AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @m_nResultCode int 
select @m_nResultCode = 100

BEGIN 
SELECT @m_szUserID = username, @m_szUserPW = password
FROM account
WHERE username = @m_szUserID;



END
```

my problem now is that I dont know how I make IFS like checking if the username is right, if the password is right.. because I always have to make different result code. Login wrong = result code 100, wrong username = 101, wrong password = 102..

Im searching for hours now but I cant find anything useful. 
Does anyone know a link where I can find helpful things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most basic procedure you can write for a login call, but in real life application you will need to check logins which exists but maybe disabled, deleted, not logged in for over some period of time and bla bla. You can add as many as check needed to make sure only authorised people has access.

Try something like this.....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AccountAuth] /* Procedure Name. */
    @m_szUserID  varchar(20),
    @m_szUserPW  varchar(50),
    @m_nResultCode int OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Password varchar(50);

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM account WHERE username = @m_szUserID)
      BEGIN
             SELECT @Password = [password]
             FROM   account
             WHERE  username = @m_szUserID;

                IF (@Password = @m_szUserPW)
                  BEGIN
                      SET @m_nResultCode = 1;  -- 1 for successful login
                  END
                ELSE
                  BEGIN
                      SET @m_nResultCode = 0;  -- 0 for Unsuccessful login
                  END 
      END
    ELSE
     BEGIN
        SET @m_nResultCode = 2; -- 2 if User Name does not exists

     END
END
```

**Calling Stored Procedure**

```
DECLARE @OUT_Result INT;

EXECUTE [dbo].[AccountAuth] @m_szUserID     = 'UserName'
                            ,@m_szUserPW    = '123456'
                            ,@m_nResultCode = @OUT_Result OUTPUT

-- Now do what ever you need to do with @OUT_Result variable.
```

Comment: SELECT 1 FROM <-- is the 1 for select only 1 row?

Comment: No it is to Select 1, because I am using `Exists` operator and exists operator returns only True/False, if it finds a row with passed Username it selects 1 and exists operator return true, when no row is return select returns nothing and exists operator returns Null and you will never enter the IF block, instead it goes to the ELSE block and you return a code to indicate a username does not exist. I hope this helps, thank you.